# Firebase Custom Domain | Hosting's DNS request for foo.bar.com failed; contact your DNS provider for support

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, a-records

We get the following error when adding a custom domain in firebase

[image]

Also, notice that the `Prepare domain` step is just blank on `Advanced` `Setup mode` which should have instructions to add an `A` record and `TXT` record/s. Clicking `Verify` does not do anything.

But on `Quick setup`, the instructions to add `CNAME` is there

[image]

We'd like to push for the `Advanced` setup and add an `A` record because that's how we've done it on all our existing custom domains.

Also, the domain we're adding is from the DNS of a new external customer. We've done similar setup for other external customers before and didn't have this issue.

Also, let's say we're getting the error from adding `foo.bar.com`. If we try to add `baz.bar.com`, we don't get any error and there are instructions on the `Advanced` setup as expected.

How do we troubleshoot further? Thanks!

EDIT: we we're able to fully setup `baz.bar.com` (but still NOT `foo.bar.com`). Our customer mentioned that `foo.bar.com` is NOT a subdomain which might be relevant to this issue but not sure what to make of that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Our custom domain (e.g. `foo.bar.com`) is now connected to firebase. I guess we just needed to wait for a few hours for the DNS records to be propagated. And the error was likely a red herring and could be ignored.

Comment: I've waited 24 hours, still nothing